# Stop the cycle of images in Bootstrap's carousel when click next, prev button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap carousel. By default is enabled cycle images. I've disabled via interval: false.

Function perfectly, but when I click prev and next buttons to move from one image to another seems that the cycle is reactivated again. I don't want that to happen.
On page loaded several carousels. Each carries a set of images from a database. Each carousel has a unique id and href buttons for each call that carousel, so each one is independent. While they all have the same name as the class.

I tried this solution, but it doesn't work ..
[Bootstrap JavaScript Carousel Doesn't Stop Cycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521165/bootstrap-javascript-carousel-doesnt-stop-cycling)

Do you know how to avoid?

Comment: Show us what you did and where your code is right now

Comment: It is was a '});' bad job.

The solution was previously linked works correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap JavaScript Carousel Doesn't Stop Cycling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521165/bootstrap-javascript-carousel-doesnt-stop-cycling)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('.carousel').each(function(){
    $(this).carousel({
        interval: false
    });
});
```

});​

source : [Bootstrap JavaScript Carousel Doesn't Stop Cycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521165/bootstrap-javascript-carousel-doesnt-stop-cycling)