# Is there anyway to turn off the automatic slide with a twitter bootstrap 3 carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want it to stop auto revolving. I've searched around and added in this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
   $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

and that doesn't do anything, so I found this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.carousel').carousel({
   pause: true,
   interval: false
  })
});
```

and that appears to work, but when I click the next/prev the automatic slide starts again

What am I missing? Everything I search for gives me both those answers.

Comment: Can you show the markup?  I think there is a `data-ride="carousel"` attribute on the wrapper div for the carousel.. If you remove it then it will prevent it from auto starting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap JavaScript Carousel Doesn't Stop Cycling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521165/bootstrap-javascript-carousel-doesnt-stop-cycling)

Comment: not a duplicate, it's a different version of bootstrap and I tried all the answers, none worked

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing `pause`. Pause expects a string, indicating the event that should pause the carousel (ie, `"hover"`).

Remove that, and just use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.carousel').carousel({
   interval: false
  })
});
```

From the docs:

> interval: The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item. If false, carousel will not automatically cycle.